# Why api data don`t want to show on index page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to connect api wtih my website, I try to make it but It doesn't work.

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.scorebat.com/video-api/v1/",function(data){
console.log(data);
var title = data.side1[0].name;
$(".title").append(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<p class="title"></p>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` output?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.success (script.js:4)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it should be

```
data[0].side1.name
```

since the data is

```
[
    {
        "title": "AC Milan - Frosinone",
        "embed": "<iframe src='https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/emb...",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/ac-milan-vs-frosinone-live-stream\/",
        "thumbnail": "https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/og\/m\/og760535.jpeg",
        "date": "2019-05-19T16:00:00+0000",
        "side1": {
            "name": "AC Milan",
            "url": "https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/live-stream\/ac-milan\/"
        },
        "side2": {
            "name": "Frosinone",
            "url": "https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/live-stream\/frosinone\/"
        },
        "competition": {
            "name": "ITALY: Serie A",
            "id": 13,
            "url": "https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/italy-serie-a-live-scores\/"
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

so first we access the first element of the array **data[0]** and get it's property **.side1**, which is another javascript object, then we get the name property of that object **.name**